# Conectar remotamente a postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Estoy tratando de conectar remotamente a postgres , ya configure los archivos (listen_addresses = '*') y (host mibasededatos miusuario 0.0.0.0/24 md5), abri el puerto 5432 en el firewall en ambas pc, le di permiso a todos los programas en el firewall de windos para recibir conexiones de cualquier ip pero recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>   Is the server running on host "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port XXXX?

Alguien puede guiarme?

Comment: Luego de configurar hiciste un reinicio del servicio de Postgres?

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo Correcto , hasta reinicie la maquina

Comment: Intenta conectar localmente con tu consola psql a ver qué sucede, puede que sea algo de tu red